# Objective-C: Grab title of web page from WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, url, webview

I'm trying to retrieve the title of a web page and display it in the NSWindows title. This application is document based and I haven't tried anything in a standalone application with an AppDelegate. How would I go forth and retrieve the title and display it in the window?

**UPDATE:** Here's my code (Note: Doesn't work quite yet)

**TitleWindow.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
@interface TitleWindow : NSWindow <NSApplicationDelegate> {

}

@property

(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSWindow *displayTitle;

@end
```

**TitleWindow.m**

```
#import "TitleWindow.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@implementation TitleWindow


- (void)displayTitle:(WebView *)sender didReceiveTitle:(NSString *)title forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    if (frame == [sender mainFrame]){
        [[sender window] setTitle:title];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Not related to Xcode.

Comment: Also, try `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"return document.title.toString();"];`

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorta like this?    - (NSString *)windowNibName
{
    // Override returning the nib file name of the document
    // If you need to use a subclass of NSWindowController or if your document supports multiple NSWindowControllers, you should remove this method and override -makeWindowControllers instead.
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"return document.title.toString();"];
}</pre></code>

Comment: @H2CO3 The comments won't let me place code in the syntax view... So I don't know what to tell ya haha

Comment: Wrap it between backticks, `like this`. But anyway, loads of code is not suited for comments. You don't need any of that declaration, I know you are trying to make a separate method. You don't need to replicate for me Xcode's unhelpful commentary either.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you (lol sorry for the spelling error). It's strange that Stackoverflow makes comment formatting so difficult if you're just starting to use it. I updated my original post with what I have so far.

Comment: Thanks, viewing that.

Comment: @H2CO3 Okay sweet! I meant "Thank you" not "That you" at the beginning, lol stupid spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

To get an NSWebViews page title.

You use it's **[mainFrameTitle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001903-SW30)**

```
NSString * pageTitleString =[_webView mainFrameTitle];
    NSLog(@"%@" , pageTitleString);
```

[Read the Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

example 2.

[WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:)

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)webFrame{

    [_window setTitle:[_webView mainFrameTitle]];

    }
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

I have not really built a document based app before. So setting one up to display a web view was fun :-P.

Which leads me to think the problem is two fold.

---

The first thing I released is just adding the example 2 code to the document.m is not enough.

The webview needs a delegate.

What worked for me and may not be (probably not) the right way to do it was in the **Document.xib**  with the webview selected.

The Connections Inspector at the top shows you the ***frameLoadDelegate***.

I connected this to the **file's Owner** by dragging it over to the **file's Owner** in the *Place holder*s pane.

This worked.

And each time I changed the webpage from within the document the title changed along with it.

[image]

---

The second thing to note is I think the real method of setting the documents title is:

```
[self setDisplayName:@"a title"];
```

which works when set in:

```
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController

{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];


    // Add any code here that needs to be executed once the windowController has loaded the document's window.

 NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_theUrls];
    [[_webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
     [self setDisplayName:@"a title"];
}
```

And a normal string, But if I change it to:

```
[self setDisplayName:[_webView mainFrameTitle]];
```

It does not work as the frame is not loaded yet so there is no title.

So you would think then that [self setDisplayName:[_webView mainFrameTitle]]; would work in the WebFrameLoadDelegate. No it does not. And I am not sure why.

So for now you may want to use the code in example 2 code.

Comment: Okay sweet. I updated my original post with what I have so far. I'm starting to get the gist of what I need, but I'm a little lost.

Comment: It's still not displaying. The code compiles perfectly though.